# asp.net use details view if 1 record is returned and gridview if more than one record

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview, sqldatasource

I'm using a details view and a sqldatasource control to populate it.   Every once in a while i get an error message because more than one row is returned.  How can I have the data display in a gridview instead if more than one row is returned?

Answer (score 1):

Databind to both and put this in the OnDataBound event or wherever appropriate in your code.  (Obviously you'll need to tweak the code for the names of your objects)

```
if(myDataTable.Rows.Count > 1)
{
   myGridView.Visible = true;
   myDetailsView.Visible = false;

}
else
{
  myGridView.Visible = false;
   myDetailsView.Visible = true;
}
```